# No item exists when I add a document to my library

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-server, edit-form

I've an issue when I try to add a document to my library.

I've the form to upload a file and when I click OK in place of having the form for metadata I get a SharePoint error.

I can't see the complete log with correlationID because I'm in a sandbox solution.

> No item exists at `http://test/Forms/EditForm.aspx? Mode=Upload&CheckInComment=&ID=60&RootFolder=/folderTest&IsDlg=1`.
>       It may have been deleted or renamed by another user.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. 
>       For more information, contact your site administrator.

I don't understand because with another doclib it works.

Comment: the library is custom or Sharepoint Out of box?.

Comment: it's a standard sharepoint library

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct ? It would mean http://test directs you to the SP Doc Lib ? Just checked on my environment and http://test should be the complete path to the DocLib.

Comment: I don't have hand in the url because it's the form from SharePoint with my meta and when i click save, i got this error :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my library and recreated one and now it works.
the myster of SharePoint